# Changing Virtuemart Checkout Page Shipping address label

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

[image: I need to change the Shipment Addresses to Shipping address]

Please check this page:

https://newbabyhampers.com.au/index.php/checkout

I need to change the label of Shipment Addresses to Shipment address. I am using VM2 for this site. I have searched in all language files. But I cant find any HTML code or Language file text. I have also activated IceVMcart module. I really need to deliver this site soon. Where can I edit this label?

Comment: I think this can help you out: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=104216.0

Comment: thanks. I got some idea from this forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution

I have edited 'en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini' in public_html/administrator/language/en-GB. All I needed to do was to change the COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_FORM_SHIPTO_LBL Label -> 'Shipment Address'. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 3):

The output is overridden, please check:

`templates/*your_template/html/com_virtuemart/cart/default_pricelist.php`

*your_template = your active template name

The default value is: `<?php echo JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_FORM_SHIPTO_LBL'); ?>`

You could create a language override for this variable using:

```
Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I see but the value is default there. this is the value there <span class="vmicon vm2-shipto-icon"></span>
  <strong><?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_FORM_SHIPTO_LBL'); ?></strong></span>